# How big do hyper-reals get?

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, big-numbers

Let's assume there is some non-standard model of the reals containing a number $N$ that is larger than any real number.

> Suppose $\exists N\in {^*}\mathbb{R} ( \forall r\in\mathbb{R}: r<N).$

Now I know I can find even larger unlimited hyper-reals $2N,3N...$ which are smaller than $N^2,N^3...$ which are still hyper-reals because of closure under multiplication.

However, for ordinal numbers I have heard that matters become tricky around the $\varepsilon = \omega^{\omega^{\omega^{...^{...}}}}$ numbers.

So given my unlimited $N$ I think I should be able to reach $N^N, N\uparrow\uparrow N$ and so on. As far as I can work out, Knuth's arrow notation is defined recursively in $\mathcal{L}_\mathbb{R}$, so I think $N\uparrow^n N$ is well defined for finite $n$. I am less certain if it will transfer and give me $N\uparrow^N N$.

Something like the process used to compute Rayo's number on the other hand, seems outside of the bounds of $\mathcal{L}_\mathbb{R}$, so I would be very surprised if it could be generalised to make large hyperreals.

Moreover, is there some function (maybe $Tree(n)?)$, that is no longer defined for hypernatural inputs? And is there a sense in which the result of such a function could be "too big to be a hyper-real"?

I ask this last question because it seems possible to me that the answer could depend on which particular hyper-real field is being studied.

Comment: Have you read about the "transfer principle" for the hyperreals? I feel like that basically answers all aspects of your question, but if you've read about it and still have questions then maybe that can help refine your question post.

Comment: To expand a bit.. with most versions of "the hyperreals" and "the transfer principle", literally *every* function $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ (not just definable ones) extends to the hyperreals, and its first-order properties transfer. There's no need to worry about making recursive definitions work, or whatnot. The Rayo's number construction is a bit tricky to make sense of even for just standard natural numbers in the first place, but if you've done that then it will extend to the hypernaturals with minimal fuss.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think that answers my question, if any function even something with such an awkward definition as Rayo's will transfer nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most convincing way of answering this question is in an axiomatic approach to nonstandard analysis, such as Nelson's IST.  Here infinitesimals (as well as unlimited numbers) are found within the "ordinary" real number line $\mathbb R$.  They are detected by a new one-place predicate "standard".  Thus, a positive infinitesimal is a real number smaller than every positive standard real number.  An $N$ such as you are describing is a nonstandard natural number (bigger than every standard natural number).  IST is a conservative extension of ZFC.

From this point of view, it is evident that all the usual constructions you mentioned carry over, and you can construct as big a number compared to $N$ as you wish, by all the usual techniques.

Provided such constructions do not use the axiom of choice, they can also be carried out in the framework [SPOT](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/spot.html) which is conservative over ZF.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But for something like Rayo(n), even though the sequence has an extension into the hypernaturals, I'm not sure if it's growth rate will transfer. Could it be that a sequence that grows slower than Rayo(n) on the naturals, will grow faster on the hypernaturals?

Comment: Is Rayo(n) done in ZF?

Comment: Yes, but it is second order, quantifying over all Godel-coded formulae.
I think the transferred statement would only apply to the internal formulae?

Comment: @Numeral, in axiomatic nonstandard analysis, there are no external sets.  So the standard sets correspond to the natural extensions of the model-theoretic frameworks, whereas all sets correspond to the internal sets of the model-theoretic frameworks.